# Continue an infinite CSS animation that gets stopped until its last frame

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a defined CSS class `spin` that creates a simple CSS animation spinner on an element

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.spin {
  animation: spin .8s linear .15s infinite;
}
```

The `spin` class is added and removed via JavaScript, however when the class is removed the animation abruptly cuts and the first frame is displayed. Is there are way to have the browser continue to animate the element until it reaches the last frame?

I tired doing multiple combinations of `animation-fill-mode`, or setting `animation-iteration-count: 1` on the "resting" element (i.e., the same element when it does not have the `spin` class) but nothing worked. Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we combine it with the [`animationiteration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationiteration_event) event, we can do it.

```js
const spin = document.querySelector(".spin");

let iterationCount = 0;
let isMouseover = 0;

spin.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
  iterationCount = 1;
  if (iterationCount && isMouseover) {
    spin.classList.remove("animation");
  } else {
    iterationCount = 0;
  }
});

spin.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  isMouseover = 1;
});

spin.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  isMouseover = 0;
  spin.classList.add("animation");
});
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spin {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border-right: 4px solid green;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}

.spin.animation {
  animation: spin .8s linear .15s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin animation"></div>
```

Works with click also:

```js
const spin = document.querySelector(".spin");

let iterationCount = 0;
let isClicked = 0;

spin.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
  iterationCount = 1;
  if (iterationCount && isClicked) {
    spin.classList.remove("animation");
  } else {
    iterationCount = 0;
  }
});

spin.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (isClicked) {
    isClicked = 0;
    spin.classList.add("animation");
  } else {
    isClicked = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spin {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border-right: 4px solid green;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}

.spin.animation {
  animation: spin .8s linear .15s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin animation"></div>
```

Comment: That pauses the animation in its current frame, I want it to continue until the last frame! (for context, it's used for a "syncing" spinner that has two rounded arrows pointing at each other in a circle - so stopping them in the middle instead of completing the circle just looks off)

Comment: Nice solution! I guess there's currently no way to do it with only CSS, but as my app already relies on JavaScript, might as well use this solution :)